# Generic callback object, but I need the type parameter inside methods

Tags: java, android, callback

Inside my android app, I currently have methods that look like below code. 
Since they all need a callback object that basically does the same thing and I would like to try to eliminate the duplicated code seen below.

The object that gets posted via the `mBus.post(response);` statement needs to be the specific type.

```
@Subscribe
public void onLeave(LeaveRequest event) {
    mRailsApi.leave(event.getEmail(), event.getPassword(),
            new Callback<LeaveResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError arg0) {
                    LeaveResponse response = new LeaveResponse();
                    response.setSuccessful(false);
                    mBus.post(response);
                }

                @Override
                public void success(LeaveResponse leaveResponse,
                        Response arg1) {
                    // need to create one since the api just returns a
                    // header with no body , hence the response is null
                    LeaveResponse response = new LeaveResponse();
                    response.setSuccessful(true);
                    mBus.post(response);
                }
            });
}

@Subscribe
public void onGetUsers(GetUsersRequest event) {
    mRailsApi.getUsers(mApp.getToken(), new Callback<GetUsersResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError arg0) {
            GetUsersResponse response = (GetUsersResponse) arg0.getBody();
            response.setSuccessful(false);
            mBus.post(response);
        }

        @Override
        public void success(GetUsersResponse getUsersResponse, Response arg1) {
            getUsersResponse.setSuccessful(true);
            mBus.post(getUsersResponse);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is what I have come up with so far.  It seems to work but I am wondering if there is a better solution.  
One thing that bothers me is, that I have both the type parameter for the class and I am passing in the class to the constructor.  It seems like I should not need to pass in the same info in two different ways.

The method calls become this:

```
    @Subscribe
    public void onLeave(LeaveRequest event) {
        System.out.println("inside api repo - making leave request");
        LeaveResponse response = new LeaveResponse();
        mRailsApi.leave(event.getEmail(), event.getPassword(),
                new RailsApiCallback<LeaveResponse>(mBus, LeaveResponse.class ));
    }
```

And this is the callback class :

```
public class RailsApiCallback<T extends BaseResponse> implements Callback<T> {

    private Bus mBus;
    private Class mType;

    public RailsApiCallback(Bus bus, Class type) {
        super();
        mBus = bus;
        mType = type; 
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
        T response = (T) retrofitError.getBody();
        response.setSuccessful(false);
        mBus.post(mType.cast(response));
    }

    @Override
    public void success(T convertedResponse, Response rawResponse) {
        T response = null;
        try {
            response = (T) (convertedResponse != null ? convertedResponse : mType.newInstance());
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        response.setSuccessful(true);
        mBus.post(mType.cast(response));
    }
}
```

Comment: I see the point of the "What you can and cannot do",  but it makes it difficult for these old questions.  I guess what I really should have done, is posted my updated code a while back , before it was answered,  but it is hard to remember to follow up on unanswered  questions

Comment: In your `public void success(LeaveResponse leaveResponse, Response arg1) {` method you are creating a new `LeaveResponse` and posting it to the bus, while doing nothing with the former. Is that intended behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> One thing that bothers me is, that I have both the type parameter for the class and I am passing in the class to the constructor. It seems like I should not need to pass in the same info in two different ways.

The reason for why you have to do that is because of [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Simply put, the generic class is only known during compile-time.

---

- This call is unnecessary in your constructor: `super();`
- All your fields should be marked with `final`.
- `Class mType;` should be `Class<T> mType;`
- I believe the `mType.cast` is unnecessary here:

  ```
  mBus.post(mType.cast(response));
  ```

  simply `mBus.post(response);` is enough. The eventbus will automatically detect the class by calling `obj.getClass()` and invoke the appropriate listeners.

  In fact, your `response` variable is already declared as `T response;` so I don't see what good casting it will do.

Comment: Thanks for the review,  I have to go back and see what I ended up with for this ... it was a while ago.  I figured out the type erasure part, and realized that passing in a class was not so good.  I think I ended up passing in an instance of a class rather than Blah.class

Comment: @nPn I don't see what good passing in an instance of the class does. You might want to post a follow-up question, I hope to answer quicker if you do :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my updated code:

```
@Subscribe
public void onLeave(LeaveRequest event) {
    System.out.println("inside api repo - making leave request");
    mRailsApi.leave(event.getEmail(), event.getPassword(),
            new RailsApiCallback<LeaveResponse>(mBus, new LeaveResponse() ));
}   


public class RailsApiCallback<T extends BaseResponse> implements Callback<T> {

    private Bus mBus;
    private T mResponse;

    public RailsApiCallback(Bus bus, T response) {
        super();
        mBus = bus;
        mResponse = response; 
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
        System.out.println(retrofitError.toString());
        T response = (T) retrofitError.getBody() != null ? (T) retrofitError.getBody() : mResponse  ;
        response.setRawResponse(retrofitError.getResponse());
        response.setSuccessful(false);
        mBus.post(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void success(T convertedResponse, Response rawResponse) {
        System.out.println(rawResponse.getBody());
        T response = convertedResponse != null ? convertedResponse : mResponse ;
        response.setSuccessful(true);
        response.setRawResponse(rawResponse);
        mBus.post(response);

    }
}
```

I think the main change I did here was to pass in an instance of the response class rather than create a new instance of the class inside success method.
I don't think there was really any type checking in the original code.

Comment: Yes, creating the object outside the generic class seems like a better idea. No need to instantiate with reflection anymore.